# Convergence of the dispersion of normal distribution

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

Let $\{X_i\}$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables, with distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  Define the random variables
$$
Y_n=\frac{\max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}-\min\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}}{n}.
$$

Does $\{Y_n\}$ converge?  If yes, to what?  If not, is there a power of $n$ (at the denominator) for which it converges to a non-zero number almost certainly?  By numerical experimentation, it seems that with $n$ it converges to $0$, but with $\log n$ it stays apart from $0$.

I was wondering whether one can recover $\sigma$ with this limit process.

It's equivalent (by simmetry) to finding the limit of
$$\frac{2\cdot\max\{X_1,\dots,Xn\}}{n}$$
which is easier to compute.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105745/extreme-value-theory-show-normal-to-gumbel Refer to this question